# Use env Heroku variables into newrelic.yml file

Tags: heroku, newrelic

I need to create environment-dependent parameterization, into the newrelic.yml file.
I want to use an Heroku env var that can assume different values depending on the environment.
How can I make it?
Do I need to create files like newrelic.development, newrelic.staging, ecc. ?
Or what?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the language you're trying to use. I know in PHP for example you can use ${ENV_VAR_NAME} in the config files and it will use such a value.

I don't know if that's true of all the agent languages but let me know what language you're using and perhaps I can nudge in the right direction